# Incompatible shapes error using longformer for text classification in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, attention-model

I am using the following code to do text classification using longformer in tensorflow.  I am getting an error about incompatible shapes.  I have checked the shape of my inputs, and cannot figure out the problem. (I know this data isn't long enough to require longformer, I am using it to test my code before scaling up).

I'm not sure if its a problem on my end, or a software version issue or something.

```
!pip install transformers

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from transformers import LongformerTokenizer, TFLongformerForSequenceClassification
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler
import math
import numpy as np

positive_sentences = [
    "The weather is absolutely gorgeous today.",
    "I'm so grateful for the support of my friends and family.",
    "I achieved my personal best in the race!",
    "The new cafe in town serves amazing coffee.",
    "I love spending time with my adorable pets.",
    "I received a surprise gift from a dear friend.",
    "The sunrise this morning was breathtaking.",
    "I'm excited about the upcoming vacation.",
    "The concert last night was incredibly entertaining.",
    "I'm proud of my hard work paying off.",
    "The park is a peaceful place to relax.",
    "I found a great book that I can't put down.",
    "The team's collaboration led to a successful project.",
    "I'm enjoying learning a new skill.",
    "Spending time with loved ones always brightens my day.",
    "I got a promotion at work, and it's a fantastic feeling.",
    "The movie I watched last night was heartwarming.",
    "I'm making positive changes in my daily routine.",
    "The delicious aroma of home-cooked food fills the air.",
    "I'm surrounded by inspiring and supportive people."
]

negative_sentences = [
    "The constant rain is making me feel gloomy.",
    "I'm disappointed that my plans got canceled.",
    "The traffic was horrendous this morning.",
    "I made a mistake on the important presentation.",
    "I'm feeling overwhelmed with work and tasks.",
    "The internet connection is frustratingly slow.",
    "The food I ordered was cold and tasteless.",
    "I'm exhausted after a long and stressful day.",
    "My phone battery died at the worst time.",
    "The store was out of stock of the item I needed.",
    "I lost my wallet and it's been a hassle.",
    "The loud construction noise is giving me a headache.",
    "I'm struggling to meet my deadlines.",
    "The movie I was looking forward to was disappointing.",
    "I'm not feeling well and it's affecting my mood.",
    "My computer crashed and I lost my unsaved work.",
    "The rude customer service ruined my experience.",
    "I'm frustrated with the constant delays.",
    "The rainy weather is putting me in a bad mood.",
    "I'm stressed about the upcoming exams."
]

sentences = positive_sentences + negative_sentences

labels = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    ,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentences':sentences,'labels':labels})

data = df.copy()

display(data.head(5))

tokenizer = LongformerTokenizer.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')
longformer_model = TFLongformerForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('allenai/longformer-base-4096')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['sentences'],df['labels'], stratify=df['labels'])
X_train.head(4)
display(y_train)

x_train_tokens = tokenizer(list(X_train), padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="tf")
x_test_tokens = tokenizer(list(X_test), padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors="tf")

y_train_encoded = np.array(y_train)
y_test_encoded = np.array(y_test)

display(x_train_tokens)

input_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)
attention_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32)
outputs = longformer_model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)[0]
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(outputs)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, attention_mask], outputs=[output_layer])

def lr_schedule(epoch):
    initial_lr = 0.001  # Set your initial learning rate here
    drop = 0.75
    epochs_drop = 5  # Adjust this value based on your preference
    lr = initial_lr * math.pow(drop, math.floor((1 + epoch) / epochs_drop))
    return lr

lr_scheduler = LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    [x_train_tokens['input_ids'], x_train_tokens['attention_mask']]
    , y_train
    , epochs=5
    , batch_size=5
    , validation_data=([x_test_tokens['input_ids'], x_test_tokens['attention_mask']], y_test)
    , callbacks=[lr_scheduler]
)
```

I get the following error

```
Epoch 1/5

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-696fe037ca84> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
      2 
----> 3 history = model.fit(
      4     [x_train_tokens['input_ids'], x_train_tokens['attention_mask']]
      5     , y_train

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52   try:
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/model/tf_longformer_for_sequence_classification/longformer/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/BroadcastGradientArgs_1' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>
      lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback
      ret = callback()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner
      self.ctx_run(self.run)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run
      yielded = self.gen.send(value)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one
      yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell
      yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request
      self.do_execute(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
      yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell
      return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-18-696fe037ca84>", line 3, in <cell line: 3>
      history = model.fit(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1384, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 863, in train_step
      self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 530, in minimize
      grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 583, in _compute_gradients
      grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 464, in _get_gradients
      grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
Node: 'gradient_tape/model/tf_longformer_for_sequence_classification/longformer/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/BroadcastGradientArgs_1'
Incompatible shapes: [5,512,12,514] vs. [5,512,12,513]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/model/tf_longformer_for_sequence_classification/longformer/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/BroadcastGradientArgs_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_260075]
```